# How to display two different price formats on shop page (Woocommerce)?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

**Problem:**
I need to display price like this (one with sup tag decimal & others with normal price format), so, I added the following codes.
[image]

But the codes displays like this (all the Was, Save and Sale prices show sup tag decimal).
[image]

Would you please let me know how to display normal price format for 'was' and 'save'?
**Sup tag decimal (functions.php):**

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ts_woo_decimal_price', 10, 5 );
function ts_woo_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    $price_format = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
    $decimal = sprintf( '%02d', ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 );
    return $price_format . '<sup>' . $decimal . '</sup>';
}
```

**Display Prices as “Was and Save” (functions.php):**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_simple_product_price_format', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_simple_product_price_format( $price, $product ) {
   if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
      $info_price = sprintf( __( '<div class="was-now-save" style="padding:0 10px 0 10px;"><div class="was">Was: %1$s</div><div class="save">Save: %3$s</div></div>', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price ( $product->get_regular_price() ), wc_price( $product->get_sale_price() ), wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() )  );      
   }
   return '<div style="display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">' . $price . '<span>' . $info_price . '</span></div>';
}
```

**Frontend HTML:**

```
<span class="price">
   <div style="display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
      <del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3<sup>20</sup></bdi></span></del>
      <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3<sup>14</sup></bdi></span></ins> <span class="uom">ea</span>
      <span><div class="was-now-save" style="padding:0 10px 0 10px;"><div class="was">Was: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3<sup>20</sup></bdi></span></div><div class="save">Save: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0<sup>05</sup></bdi></span></div></div></span>
   </div>
</span>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add css:

```css
sup {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup::before {
  content: ".";
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3<sup>20</sup></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3<sup>14</sup></bdi></span></ins> <span class="uom">ea</span>
<div class="was-now-save" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
<div class="was">Was: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3<sup>20</sup></bdi></span></div>
<div class="save">Save: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0<sup style="vertical-align: baseline;">05</sup></bdi></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```